# WifiManeger#scanResults() always returning empty in Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

Yes, I did take a look at all other similar question but they are not working for me. I'm trying to scan all the access points near me. This exact code works for Android 10, but in Android 6.0, specifically in Galaxy J5, the getScanResult() is always returning empty, the code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_alunos);
        setTitle(TITULO_APPBAR);
        listaAlunosView = new ListaAlunosView(this);
        configuraFabNovoAluno();
        configuraLista();
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        //Check for permissions
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                || (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
        {
            Log.i("TAG", "Requesting permissions");

            //Request permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
                            Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE},
                    123);
        }
        else
            Log.i("TAG", "Permissions already granted");


        wifiScan();
    }

 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        Log.i("TAG,", "onRequestPermissionsResult");

        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case 123:
            {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    // permission was granted
                    Log.i("TAG", "permission granted: " + permissions[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Log.i("TAG", "permission denied: " + permissions[0]);
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request.
        }
    }

private void wifiScan() {
    wifiManager.startScan();

    BroadcastReceiver wifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            boolean success = intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED, false);

            if(success) {
                List<ScanResult> scanResults = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                Log.i("SCAN RESULT:", "" + scanResults);
            } else {

            }
        }
    };
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="br.com.alura.agenda"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup">
        <activity android:name=".ui.activity.ListaAlunosActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ui.activity.FormularioAlunoActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I also turned my Location Services ON.

Can someone tell me where is the error?